# Add column to dataset in MLDB

Tags: csv, mldb

So I'm playing with http://mldb.ai/ and I have a simple question. I have a csv file that I want to import using http://mldb.ai/doc/#builtin/datasets/TabularCsvDataset.md.html

It works fine but I would like to add a column. I actually have a bunch of csv files to I will merge but in order to differentiate them I would like to add the csv file name as a value in a new column.

Say I have the file filea.csv and fileb.csv, both with columns X Y Z. I would like to add a column so I get 
X Y Z name

How do I add this column?

Answer (score 0):

The `text.csv.tabular` dataset (which has been renamed to `tabular`, as you will see in the next release) is immutable, so you cannot add columns to it. You can create a new dataset with the result of a `JOIN` or `merge` operation.